# Translating "How's the weather over there in January?"

Tags: translation, idioms

I am listening to Italian Language tapes that do not have any written material to go with them.  As I have made progress, (I am on lesson 45) I am getting a little confused.  I believe that there must be some ways of expressing things that are idIomatic - and I am wondering if the following question is because the tape is being idiomatic? 
The tape is prompting me(in English) to say
**But, how’s the weather over there in January?**
My answer was;
**Ma, come è il tempo lì a gennaio?**
The tape's answer is;
**Ma, fa tempo li en gennaio?**
Is the tape's answer right?  It is so different than what I was expecting, that I am just not sure.  Also, I just used "there~lì" in my answer, since they have not mentioned the word 'over' at all.

Is the answer they want me to learn more correct or more in common use than the answer I thought it was going to be?  Is my answer correct?

Comment: My question was, would "Ma, fa tempo lì en gennaio?" be considered a correct way of saying, "But what's the weather like there in January?" Aren't idioms fun?!

Comment: @Mrs_MG: Please, use the "Your Answer" box to write a real answer to the OP question. If you want to ask something, you can use "Ask Question".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Italian when we want to know about the weather in a given location we generally ask:

> Come è il tempo lì?

or

> Che tempo fa lì?

and [both](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/T/tempo.shtml) are translated into English as *What's the weather like over there?*. They're two equivalent forms and I'd say they are used with the same frequency (although the latter sounds more informal).

As for the preposition, *en* is not an Italian word: it might have been *in*. Anyway when you talk about a period of time with a proper noun like the name of a month you should use *a*, as you did: *a gennaio*, *ad agosto* (there's a vowel as first letter for the month, so you should use an euphonic *d*), *a settembre*, etc., but you use *in*, for example, when you're talking about a season:

> Com'è il tempo lì ***a*** gennaio? 
>   
>   Com'è il tempo lì ***in*** inverno?

Comment: Okay, thank you!  I think that means my first try was correct - except that I am still confused about why I used a gennaio, and they used en gennaio.  BUT - their answer leaves out the CHE of your second option.  Is "Fa tempo li en gennaio?" correct without the che?

Comment: Never mind!  I went back and listened to it again, about 20 times, and finally heard the che!  Thank you very much.  Learning this way is confusing... I spend a lot of time looking things up - which, I guess is not a BAD thing. ;-)

Comment: @Msfolly your version is correct. As for the tape version, is it a transcript you've done or is it written as you reported it?

Comment: @Msfolly It is not bad at all! ;)

Comment: Purtroppo, there is no written transcript at all - apparently by design...  Their explanation is that it will mix up my pronunciation.  I wish there was, though, because they talk very fast, and since I am new, sometimes I do not even know what I am supposed to be hearing!

Comment: Also, I just saw your explanation about 'a' and 'in', and I am thrilled with it.  Thank you!  (I know a little Spanish, and it is actually FIGHTING with the Italian a little.)

Comment: @Msfolly You're very welcome! For any question, I'm here (if I can answer). I don't know Spanish so I cannot see the conflict.

Comment: In my lessons, saying "Fa brutto tempo!" means "The weather is bad" or literally, "Makes bad, the weather." Also, "Fa brutto tempo?" Means "Is the weather bad?" So, as a beginner, if I saw written, "Ma, fa tempo lì en gennaio?" I would probably literally interpret it as "But, how makes the weather there in January?" or "What's the weather like in January?" So wonder why that would be wrong? [As an aside, I would hate to try to learn the language without a written copy. I use Babbel, which does written, spoken, and hearing immersive learning of the language. But, I'm just a beginner, too!]

Comment: @Mrs_MG, I'm not sure I've fully understood your question. Are you asking why the correspondence between the Italian sentence "Ma, fa tempo lì en gennaio?" and the English sentence "What's the weather like in January?" is not exact?

Comment: @Mrs_MG Sorry for my tardiness. The quoted sentence is not correct from a grammatical point of view: as Msfolly noticed in her first comment to my answer, and as she later found out, there's a missing *che*. Also, as I said, *en* is not an Italian preposition: it might have been an *in*. A correct alternative for asking «(But,) what's the weather like over there in January?» is: «***Che*** tempo fa lì ~~*en*~~ ***in*** gennaio?», where *en* should be cancelled. And yes, languages are really fun! :)

Comment: @mrnld Can I use laggiù instead of lì?  For instance, if I am speaking from Italy, asking about New York, USA, it would seem to be a little more accurate in terms of distance. Ma, che tempo fa laggiù a gennaio?

Comment: @Msfolly Yes, *laggiù* seems appropriate if you want to convey the idea of a distance between where you are at the moment of speaking and the place you're asking about.